# error LNK2019 for unknown reason

Tags: c++, class

My code is like this:

Basic.h

```
#define Type double
```

Model.h

```
#include "Basic.h"

class Model{
 protected:
  int _N;
 public:
  Model(int _N, Type* config){ config=new Type[N]; _N=N}
  virtual Type compute();
}
class Model1: public Model{
 protected:
  int _Nr,_Nc;
 public:
  Model1(int Nr, int Nc, Type* config):Model(Nr*Nc,config){_Nr=Nr;_Nc=Nc;}
  virtual Type compute();
}
class Model2: Public Model{
 public:
  Model2(int N,Type* config):Model(N,config){/*other unrelated codes*/}
  virtual Type compute();
}
```

Model1.cpp

```
#include "Model.h"

Type Model1::compute(){
/*definition*/
}
```

Model2.cpp

```
#include "Model.h"

Type Model2::compute(){
/*definition*/
}
```

Method.h

```
#include "Model.h"

void Method(Model* sys);
```

Method.cpp

```
#include "Method.h"

void Method(Model* sys){ 
Type a=sys->compute();
/*code*/}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Method.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  Model* sys=new Model2();
  Method(sys);
  /*code*/
}
```

I can't find any problems but the compiler keeps complaining "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol void __cdecl Method(class Model *) referenced in function _main".

I am so frustrated because I am a beginner of this and fail to find out the key. I don't know what can cause this: is it anything wrong in my #define? Or it is because different subclass have functions with the same name(seems it should be OK)? Or there is other bugs? I don't even know to add what tags to this question...

Can anyone help me to figure this out? Thanks a lot!

---

Thanks for suggestions and I have updated the questions to make sure all the constructors are contained.

Comment: have you written the constructors ?

Comment: What is this syntax doing : `Model1():Model();`?

Comment: can you show us how are you building this?

Comment: Yes I have written the constructors. It's like: Model(int N, Type* config){ config=new Type[N];} I didn't put it in the question because I guess there is no bug in constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if Method.cpp is not part of the project, so it's not compiled and the linker can't find `Method`.

You should add all CPP files to your project - Main, Method, Model1 and Model2. While you're at it, make sure the H files are all there, as well.

Comment: Well I have checked it again and make sure that all the files are in the project so it is so weird..

Comment: Remove the rest of your code (after the call to Method) and see if the error persists. The problem may be someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some semicolons in the Model.h I think.
You need to end the class definitions with semicolon.

For example:

```
class Model{
 protected:
  int _N;
 public:
  Model(int _N, Type* config){ config=new Type[N]; _N=N}
  virtual Type compute();
};
```

Not sure if this is the solution to your problem however. But missing semicolons can bring up all sorts of issues.